# Security threat with browser extensions

Tags: google-chrome, security, permissions, passwords

When we add chrome extensions in the browser (eg. for dark mode or blocking ads) it asks for few permissions. Specific example, I am concerned with is about DARK READER extension.

Link : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=en-US

Now this kind of extension asks for permission as follows:

[image]

I want to know if I give this permission, can this extension read passwords which I type?
What security threats does it pose and how to safeguard myself from them?

I have read that I should use incognito mode. Please someone elaborate.

Comment: If the password is physically entered on the page it can be intercepted by any extension with these permissions.

Comment: Is it safe in incognito?

Comment: Extensions don't run in incognito by default. There's an switch for that in chrome://extensions page when you click "details" button of an extension.

Comment: Right. Thank you.